# type 3 fonts allowing \psfrag

Tags: psfrag

I need help producing a file without type three fonts but at the same time allowing `\psfrag` to produce LaTeX text inside figures.

Could someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: your question is completely unclear. There is no connection between the font format used and psfrag.